# windows phone, wsdl function "not found" error

Tags: php, web-services, windows-phone-7, wsdl

I am programming a little windows phone 7 application. It should consume webservices. I tested sucessfully the code in a xammp (local) environment, but if on a free webhoster I get an error "notFound". I ve tested everything and now I need help.

wsdl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tns="http://schwarzes-imperium.de/witzeAppWp" 
targetNamespace="http://schwarzes-imperium.de/witzeAppWp">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://schwarzes-imperium.de/witzeAppWp.wsdl" elementFormDefault="qualified"/>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="loginCheckRequest">
<wsdl:part name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="password" type="xs:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="loginCheckResponse">
<wsdl:part name="Result" type="xs:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ausgabeRequest">
<wsdl:part name="text" type="xs:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ausgabeResponse">
<wsdl:part name="Result" type="xs:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="witzeAppWpPortType">
<wsdl:operation name="loginCheck">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:loginCheckRequest"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:loginCheckResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ausgabe">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:ausgabeRequest"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:ausgabeResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="witzeAppWpBinding" type="tns:witzeAppWpPortType">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="loginCheck">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:#loginCheck" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output> 
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ausgabe">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:#ausgabe" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output> 
</wsdl:operation>   
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="witzeAppWpService">
<wsdl:port name="witzeAppWpPort" binding="tns:witzeAppWpBinding">
  <soap:address location="http://schwarzes-imperium.de/witzeAppWp.php"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

php-file

```
<?php
include 'sql.php';
function loginCheck($name, $password){
if ($password == "test") 
{
    return "JA";
}else 
{
    return "NEIN";
}
}
function ausgabe($id){
#$result = sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM witze_tb");
#return mysql_result($result, $id, 1); 
return $id;
}
$server = new SoapServer("witzeAppWp.wsdl");
$server->addFunction("loginCheck");
$server->addFunction("ausgabe");
$server->handle();
?>
```

Any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the similar issue. I am also looking for how to do SOAP call on WindownsPhone and found [Is WSDL compatible with Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634902/is-wsdl-compatible-with-windows-phone-8)
 I am still looking for a easier way.

Answer (score 0):

WSDL link should be an absolute path, and are you sure you are getting your functions right?
I remember that webservices always wanted to have the args in an array. such as:

```
$webserivce = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8080/Service.svc?wsdl');   
$welcome = array('name' => 'Marijke',
             'surname' => 'Hakvoort');
$response = $webservice->WelcomeMessage($welcome);
echo $response->WelcomeMessageResult;
```

In which WelcomeMessage is a function, name and surname the args.